# Are there any public IOTA.AS nodes?

Tags: chrysalis, iota-as

The [latest blogpost about IOTA.AS](https://blog.iota.org/unclaimed-tokens-community-treasury-and-iota-as-faq/) did not make anything much clearer. It suggests to ask on Discord, but searching for "IOTA AS" on discord is not very fruitful (Discord seems to search for messages that contain both words instead of the actual phrase).

So I'll try it here: Are there any IOTA.AS node out there (except the one coordinator node that is currently run by the Foundation)? And in particular, are there any nodes with public API endpoints?

If you do not believe in IOTA.AS having any success, you can still donate your IOTA.AS to people who believe in it (making them more happy at least in the short term). And if you believe in IOTA.AS having even only minimal success, you may want to consolidate your "auto-migrated" coins or want to set up dust allowance for your donation address.

Both of this is incredibly complicated without having public API nodes available.

And I guess nobody is happy if I spin up a VM with a IOTA.AS node, ask for peers, wait until the node is synched, do what I want, wait for it to be confirmed, tell my peers that they can remove me again, and destroy the VM again.

(I've done similar things with some other niche cryptocurrencies, but it is not fun for me either.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so far no one asked to peer with any of the IF nodes. Right now there are three nodes + coordinator node running.
From my personal knowledge there are no public nodes for IOTA AS.

The details to setup an IOTA AS node are available at the end of the following blog post:
https://blog.iota.org/the-new-chrysalis-network-is-live/

All the best,
Antonio